# is there an equivalent of rails try in django?

Tags: django

In Rails, you can call try when you're not sure if the object will exist or not.

```
def method(foo)
  foo.try(:bar)
end
```

if `foo` exists, it will call `foo.bar`, and if not, it will return `nil`. Is there a similar mechanism in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope there is not. You have to catch the exception and return `None` instead:

```
def method(foo):
    try:
        return foo.bar
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):
        return None
```

Alternatively, you can check if the given object has that attribute using [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def method(foo):
   return getattr(foo, "bar", None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this should work

```
def method(foo):
    return foo.bar if foo and hasattr(foo, 'bar') else None
```